# Upload several images to Google sites

Tags: images, upload, google-classic-sites

How can I upload several images to a Google sites page simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you can, but here are two possible hacks:

1. Compression - Use an archiving program like Winzip to condense all your files into one folder on your hard drive and then upload. No need to upload files one at a time in this way.
2. [Open several tabs on your browser](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/sites/thread?tid=2bcd888bec7e0eaf&hl=en) and upload each separately.